# Django RF. how to get a Django Model with nested relationship

Tags: django, testing, serialization, django-rest-framework

While testing my features in a Django Rest framework App, I need to get an object, let's call it `Foo` and this object has some nested relationships. I can get it by my making a request with the `APIClient` as such :

```
class FooTest(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient()

  def test_foo_feature(self):
    foo_id = generator.generateFoo().id
    foo = self.client.get(reverse('foo-detail', args=[foo_id])).data
```

**I was wondering if I could call directly my `FooSerializer` in a certain way to get my `Foo` object with the nested relationships**, instead of passing by the view with the help of the `APIClient` because simply calling `Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)` doesn't return the nested relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to pass an instance directly to a serializer like this (as specified in the [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects)):

```
from some_app.serializers import FooSerializer

class FooTest(TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
    self.client = APIClient()

  def test_foo_feature(self):
    foo_id = generator.generateFoo().id
    foo = Foo.objects.get(id=foo_id)
    serialized_data = FooSerializer(foo).data
```